# Macro to create dynamic range with variable rows and columns

Tags: vba, excel

Very simple scenario: One spreadsheet where the columns and rows will change every time I update it; the spreadsheet will always begin on `A1`.

Here is the code I have now that is not working:

```
Dim LR As Long
LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("A1l:BM" & LR).Select
```

Can you please let me know what needs to be changed so that it will always capture the current region of columns x rows?

Thanks!

Comment: check your address in `Range("A1l:BM" & LR).Select` : there is defenetly something wrong with `A1l`. Should it be `A1` or `AL1`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select the entire used range in you sheet, you can simply do it by using:

```
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select
```

Comment: I had another macro before this one that worked but it would store the range every time instead of changing it when I tested new worksheets:

Comment: Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="CMC_Data", RefersToR1C1:= _
        "='CMC Hours Reported'!R1C1:R917C22"

Comment: I am afraid that I don't follow you on this one. Perhaps I am not understanding exactly what you need to accomplish.

Comment: Ok.  I am looking for the entire piece of code to create a range.  I have a worksheet that I will run the code on (beginning in A1) but each time the worksheet will have a different number of rows and columns.  I already have the code to delete any previous ranges that were stored in the workbook, that will run before this one does.  I found macros with variable rows or macros with variable columns; but I not both.  The example above shows where the range keeps going to row 917 every time and that's not what I need; I just need it to go to the last row with data and the last column with data.

Comment: In that case I still believe that the piece of code I have provided should do the trick.

Comment: Found it:                                                     LastRow = Cells(65536, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = Cells(1, 255).End(xlToLeft).Column
MyArea = "='" & ActiveSheet.Name & "'!R1C1:R" & LastRow & "C" & LastCol
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="CMC_Data", RefersToR1C1:=MyArea